# Почему не выводит запятую WinForms Keys при указании Oemcomma?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

При помощи представленного фрагмента кода в ячейках DataGridView должны выводиться только цифры и запятая, однако запятая не вводиться ни при одной раскладке клавиатуры.

```
private: System::Void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs^ e) {
    TextBox ^tb = (TextBox^)e->Control;
    tb->MaxLength = 4;
    tb->KeyPress += gcnew KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MyForm::tb_KeyPress);
    }

void tb_KeyPress(Object^  sender, KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
    if (!(Char::IsDigit(e->KeyChar) || e->KeyChar == (char)Keys::Back || e->KeyChar == (char)Keys::Oemcomma))
        e->Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: По-моему лучше нажать кнопку и посмотреть код символа `e->KeyChar ` чем гадать *почему не выводит запятую*. Раз не выводит - то код не совпадает. Посмотреть можно в дебагере.

Comment: Как вариант - не ту кнопку жмёте. Oemcomma = 188, это скорее всего сканкод запятой на доп-клавиатуре (или что-то такое). А у KeyPress KeyChar  - скорее всего уже приведенный код, т.е. код запятой который равен 44 или `','`.

Comment: Очень часто люди копируют данные в буфер обмена, потом из него вставляют в нужное поле (ячейка вашего грида). При этом часто при выделении захватывается часть лишних данных, которая удаляется уже после вставки. Ваш метод не позволит этого делать. Также невозможно будет скопипастить дробные числа в другой культуре (точка вместо запятой и т. п.). В общем, не делайте так. Я и сам так когда-то делал (как и многие начинающие разработчики), но потом пришёл к пониманию  работы рядовых пользователей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сканкод запятой - 44,проблема решена чтением https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx. и

e->KeyChar == (char)44